# EWS SOAP get ChangeKey from ID?

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices

using SOAP is it possible to get the ChangeKey of an item identified by Item ID ?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GetItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa565934%28EXCHG.140%29.aspx) might be what you're looking for. The response will include ChangeKey.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />
    <t:TimeZoneContext>
      <t:TimeZoneDefinition Id="GMT Standard Time" />
    </t:TimeZoneContext>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <m:GetItem>
      <m:ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
      </m:ItemShape>
      <m:ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="AAMkADY..." />
      </m:ItemIds>
    </m:GetItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```